# kinetic js group position is not correct when dragging

Tags: javascript, canvas, kineticjs

I am trying to create group object that include text,image .
I want to get right position(x,y) when dragging the group object.
Now i get minus value {x:-26,y:-18} like that.

```
 var text2=new Kinetic.Text({
        x: 40,
          y: 125,
        text: 'Time:4:20',
        fontFamily: 'Calibri',
        fontSize: 12,
        padding: 5,
        fill: 'red',
        draggable: false
      });
    var group = new Kinetic.Group({
                    width:94,
                    height:45,
                    draggable: true
                    });
                   group.on('dragend', function() {
                          alert("X:"+group.getAbsolutePosition().x+"Y:"+group.getAbsolutePosition().y);
                        });
 group.add(text2);
 layer.add(group);
stage.add(layer);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is working normally.

You have a non-draggable text on the draggable group.

This causes the text to act as a "handle" to drag whole group.

(the text does not move relative to the group.  Instead the whole group is moved by dragging the text).

So if you drag the text up and left a bit the group will be pulled up and left a bit.

Therefore the group reports negative coordinates.

Comment: what should i do to get correct position of group? At my group object include image and text and i want to drag both together and get right position of group. guide me if other way to solve.

Comment: Since the group is being dragged by the text, you are getting the correct top-left position of the group after the drag.  When you say "correct position" -- what does that mean exactly?  Do you mean the position of the text?

Comment: yup the position of text.

Comment: Ok, just add the group and text positions: var x=group.x()+text.x(); var y=group.y()+text.y();